# Reproducible shuffle on Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there an equivalent of MySQL `rand(seed)` in Postgres but in one statement because there is no way for me to guarantee that `setseed()` will be executed just before the `random()` in the same db instance. Also there is just too much columns to use a union.

Comment: Why can't you run `setseed()` before running your query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There are multiple instances which make parallel connections to the db. The seeds must not mix.

Comment: The call setseed with different values in each connection

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So apparently this works: postgres.query("select setseed(0.3); select * from events order by random()")
How can i do the second query with sequelise model ?